# Shared lib folder in JBoss eap 6.3

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to put my common jar files into JBoss server lib folder but I am getting ClassNotFoundException. Any suggestion on how to make it work(Similar to sharedlib folder in websphere).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jboss module for that. The idea is to copy your jar into the module directory of jboss eap and create a module descriptor (declares your module name, jar that implements the module, and dependencies).

For using the module, you specify the dependency in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of your app

You can find an example here:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

Note: The guide provived says that module path is JBOSS_HOME\modules, but for a eap 6.3 the path is JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base

Comment: is there a way to define wild card matching in JBOSS EAP module.xml like this? e.g. `<resource-root path="*.jar"/>`

Comment: I don´t think so, but is has been asked https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODULES-99